# Adding token to view make laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have link like this with token:

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/users/submit/' . $id->id) }}?_token={{ csrf_token() }}">Submit New</a>
```

which produce url:

> http://example.com/users/submit/20?_token=fpf0LwHyf0JGBg0fnixjRFo1B5GgUM3RDp6dVgUU

Now in my controller I've added condition which check one column in database and based on this is returning different views.

```
public function wrongIdSubmit($Id) {

    $submits = self::$user->where('submit_id', $Id)->first();

    if (!$txid) {
        App::abort(404);
    }       

    if($submits->submit_id > 3) {
        return View::make('fail',[              
            'submits' => $submits               
        ]);         
    }

    else {
        return View::make('submit',[            
            'submits' => $submits           
        ]);
    }
}
```

My question is how to pass this token `?_token={{ csrf_token() }}` to return View::make along with $submits variable? Because like is now I've got error

> production.ERROR: Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the token to the form itself. You cannot pass it in the URL. Add the following to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

Comment: And this should ensure me that page wont be accessible from not logged in users when my route is like this: `Route::post('/submit/{Id}', ['uses' => 'UsersController@Submit', 'before' => 'auth']);` since I have ` 'before' => 'auth']`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provide function which returns you direct input hidden field with token.

```
csrf_field()
```

It will Generates an HTML hidden input field containing the value of the CSRF token.

so you can try like this:

```
return View::make('fail',[              
   'submits' => $submits,
   'token' => csrf_field()               
]);
```

and in view just print:

```
{!! $token !!}
```

or direct also like:

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

out put will be like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="*****" />
```

Best of luck..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but got an error `Call to undefined function csrf_field()`. Bellow answer is working fine but I'm not sure if this will secure the page so another user and/or un-logged users will not be able to visit the page

Comment: @VLS which version of Laravel you are using currently ?

Comment: This project run on 4.2

Comment: `csrf_field()` is only available >= 5.1

Comment: But this one is working directly on view page `{{ Form::hidden('_token', csrf_token()) }}`

Comment: Yes @VLS Sorry it's Laravel version problem. it's available in >= Laravel 5.1